# access violation error when using map in dll

Tags: c++, dll

I tried to create a win32 dll using c++. It has a map declared globally. But when I try to access the map using the dll its giving a run time error that: **WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000008**. How to solve it?

Declaration:    `static map<int,urllib> url_container;`

The urllib is a class.

Error occurance:    `url_container[ucid] = urllib();`

The error occurs at the above point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code

```
url_container[ucid] = urllib()
```

get called in a static initialiser for an other global object?  If so there is no guarantee that `url_container` has been consutructed before the other global object.

Use an accessor function to control when the object is created, or use a singleton library like [boost singleton](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/pool/doc/implementation/singleton.html)

Accessor example

```
map<int,urllib> & get_url_container()
{
    static map<int,urllib> url_container;
    return url_container
}
```

As an aside I would suggest you try to avoid global objects.  As you could spend the rest of your life debugging issues like this.  Eventually the construction of one global object will depend on another etc. and the order of construction is not defined so it might work on one platform/compiler and fail on another.

Answer (score 1):

I assume urllib is a type or class and not a function?

It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with your code.  In the debugger, what do you see on the call stack when the exception happens?  It would be helpful to see exactly where it's running into the access violation.

Comment: urllib is a class. And the exception occurs when the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try inserting it if it doesnt exist in the map yet, although what you have should be fine

```
url_container.insert ( pair<int,urllib>(ucid,urllib()) );
```

Comment: Have you tried this: urllib* test = new urllib(); just to see if that works?  If you decide to use the reference in the map, dont forget to delete it at the end

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only reasonable way to solve access violations is to use a debugger.